# Submitting a file with jQuery.ajax gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, form-data

I am trying to submit a file from a form using jQuery's `ajax` method:

```
var ofile=document.getElementById('image').files[0];
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image",ofile);

$.ajax({
    url:'elements/save_elements',
    data:formdata,
    type:'POST'
});
```

This results in the error `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData`.

What causes this error? It doesn't happen on the actual `formdata.append`, but inside jQuery.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: okk, no probs sir , i got the answer

Answer (score 112):

I was having the same problem with similar code. There's a severe dearth of information about this error, so since the OP didn't elaborate:

With some debugging I realised the error was being thrown by the ajax call in the depths of jquery, not the actual append.
Turns out I'd forgotten to add `processData: false, contentType: false` to the ajax request; Doing so fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I read about processData:false... but not contentType

Comment: Turns out if you misspell ``processData`` as ``proccessData`` you will also get the same error. Reasonable.

Comment: i am so glad this was the first thing that showed up when i searched google for the error mesaage.

Comment: @w-- Lucky you! With me it was the 50+ thing I read. Because I -- after 15 years of coding -- did not google the error message right away but instead googled all kinds of ill-phrased wishes …

Comment: But.. I need to use multipart/form-data as my content-type.. because that's what my REST api is looking for... maybe I can just... assume incoming requests are of type multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 8):

It works fine when you add the the following to the ajax object:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

So it should look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'elements/save_elements',
    data:formdata,
    type:'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding these parameter to ajax solve the problem

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'upload_ajax.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
```